# How to make a backup and restore mysql database in VB.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, windows

how to make backup and restore database mysql in vb.net I use xampp. but when the backup process starts, loading his life progressbar.

this is my coding :

```
Private Sub btnBackup_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnBackup.Click

Dim file As String 

sfd.Filter = "SQL Dump File (*.sql)|*.sql|All files (*.*)|*.*"

sfd.FileName= "Database Backup "  + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss") + ".sql"

If sfd.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then

file = sfd.FileName

Dim myProcess As New Process()

myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe"

myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False

myProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory ="C:\xampp/mysql/bin"

myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True

myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True

myProcess.Start()

Dim myStreamWriter As StreamWriter= myProcess.StandardInput

Dim mystreamreader As StreamReader = myProcess.StandardOutput

myStreamWriter.WriteLine("mysqldump -u root --password=1 _  -h 127.0.0.1 ""minimart"" > """   file   """ ")

myStreamWriter.Close()

myProcess.WaitForExit()

myProcess.Close()

MsgBox("Backup Created Successfully!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Backup")

EndIf

End Sub
```

so I want the loading process at the command prompt in the locker with progressbar

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Your formatting is so bad that @marc_s itself gave up on fixing your code. :-) (me too)

Comment: There is a nice package on NuGet that will do the back up for you

Answer (score 0):

I have about a year trying to figure this out also. And i finally found out how.

```
 Private Sub Backup()
    Dim file As String
    sfd.Filter = "Backup file (*.mdf)|*.mdf"
    sfd.FileName = "Database Backup " & Date.Today & ".mdf"

     Try
        If sfd.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            file = sfd.FileName
            Dim DB As String = "C:\Users\Spups\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Test-javier\Test-javier\bin\Debug\Test-Javier-DB.mdf"
            Dim Log As String = "C:\Users\Spups\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Test-javier\Test-javier\bin\Debug\Test-Javier-DB_log.ldf"

            Dim BLog As String = file.Replace(".mdf", "_log.ldf")

            Dim constr As String = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Master;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
            Dim con As New SqlConnection(constr)
            SqlConnection.ClearAllPools()
            con.Open()

            Dim cmdON As New SqlCommand
            cmdON.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmdON.CommandText = "ALTER DATABASE [" & DB & "] SET ONLINE"
            cmdON.Connection = con
            cmdON.ExecuteNonQuery()

            Dim cmdOFF As New SqlCommand
            cmdOFF.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmdOFF.CommandText = "ALTER DATABASE [" & DB & "] SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE"
            cmdOFF.Connection = con
            cmdOFF.ExecuteNonQuery()

            My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(DB, file, True)
            My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(Log, BLog, True)

            cmdON.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmdON.CommandText = "ALTER DATABASE [" & DB & "] SET ONLINE"
            cmdON.Connection = con
            cmdON.ExecuteNonQuery()

            MessageBox.Show("Backup was succesful", "Test", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        End If


    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub Restore()

    Dim file As String
    ofd.Filter = "Backup file (*.mdf)|*.mdf"

    Try
        If ofd.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
            file = ofd.FileName

            Dim DB As String = "C:\Users\Spups\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Test-javier\Test-javier\bin\Debug\Test-Javier-DB.mdf"
            Dim Log As String = "C:\Users\Spups\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Test-javier\Test-javier\bin\Debug\Test-Javier-DB_log.ldf"
            Dim BLog As String = file.Replace(".mdf", "_log.ldf")

            Dim constr As String = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Master;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
            Dim con As New SqlConnection(constr)
            SqlConnection.ClearAllPools()
            con.Open()

            Dim cmdON As New SqlCommand
            cmdON.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmdON.CommandText = "ALTER DATABASE [" & DB & "] SET ONLINE"
            cmdON.Connection = con
            cmdON.ExecuteNonQuery()

            Dim cmdOFF As New SqlCommand
            cmdOFF.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmdOFF.CommandText = "ALTER DATABASE [" & DB & "] SET OFFLINE WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE"
            cmdOFF.Connection = con
            cmdOFF.ExecuteNonQuery()

            My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(DB)
            My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(Log)

            My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(file, DB, True)
            My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile(BLog, Log, True)

            cmdON.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmdON.CommandText = "ALTER DATABASE [" & DB & "] SET ONLINE"
            cmdON.Connection = con
            cmdON.ExecuteNonQuery()

                Me.TableTestTableAdapter.Fill(Me._Test_Javier_DBDataSet.TableTest)
                Me.TablePriceTableAdapter.Fill(Me._Test_Javier_DBDataSet.TablePrice)
                MessageBox.Show("Restore was succesful", "Test", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Then you can use the backup and restore sub in your button_click event or u can paste the code directly into your button_click event.

PS. DB = your database

Let me know if this helps.

Emely